# API cannot be seen by other application - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to call this API from an other application, but this API cannot be seen, why ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DAL.ViewModels
{
    public class DepartmentViewModel
    {
        public int DeptId { get; set; }
        public string DeptName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[First API Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWFPx.jpg)

[Second API Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhDIC.jpg)

> API Project

this is the code for API Project :
this is the controller
for API Project

```
using DAL.Interfaces;
using DAL.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace HRApiNew.Controllers
{ 
    [ApiController]
    public class DepartmentController : ControllerBase
    {        private readonly IDepartmentRepo _repo;
        public DepartmentController(IDepartmentRepo repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        [Route("api/Department/GetDepartment")]
        public IActionResult GetDepartment(int id)
        {
            //DepartmentViewModel departmentVM = _repo.GetDepartmentById(id);
            var departmentVM = _repo.GetDepartmentById(id);
           
            return Ok(departmentVM);
        }
        [Route("api/Department/GetDepartmentList")]
        public IActionResult GetDepartmentList()
        {
            var departments = _repo.GetDepartments();
            return Ok(departments);
        }    }}
```

---

### The following code is for the controller , where the API is called :
I mean this controller is written in the other project
where the API is should be called :

```
using HRWebAPP.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace HRWebAPP.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            DepartmentViewModel obj = new DepartmentViewModel();
            List<DepartmentViewModel> obj2 = new List<DepartmentViewModel>();
            try
            {
               
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44332");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    //HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Department/GetDepartment?id=1");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Department/GetDepartmentList");
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        //obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DepartmentViewModel>(result);
                        obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DepartmentViewModel>>(result);

                    }
                    //Send HTTP requests from here.
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            //return View(obj);
            return View(obj2);
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your questions unclear. You want to call this web api in another web api Did you write a code to call the web api ? You just posted the DAL layer code.You have added project DAL to the API project. You are getting an error, what is it?

Comment: Could you pull the relevant code samples from the screenshots into the question?